# Classic ASP on IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012) - Bad_file_name_or_number

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP web application I have installed on IIS 8.5 - Windows Server 2012. The ASP application uses VBscript for all server side logic.

After setting up the application on IIS, making sure to install the ASP/ISAPI filters/components through the server manager and also making sure to set the "Anonymous" and "Windows based" authentication to enabled, I am getting the following 500 error on my client web browser when I navigate to the root page of classic ASP application:

```
2016-08-26 18:48:54 10.121.71.194 GET /vhtrimswebquery/ |24|800a0034
|Bad_file_name_or_number 443 - 10.38.151.105 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible
;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;
+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+InfoPath.3;
+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+GM_UserLogonTimeBias:+300;+GM_UserLogonTimeUTC:
+2010-12-13+15:06:21) - 500 0 0 124
```

I don't know what I am missing. The "Default document" section in the IIS settings for the application has a default page setup which exists. If anyone has worked with this error before, can you point me in the direction as to what I can look at or update in the configuration to get the default page?

Comment: `0x800a0034 Bad file name or number` is a generic error message, related to an access violation often. the error points line 24, good place to start digging.

Comment: Enable failed request tracing as explained here http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85 . They are very handy specially in case of ASP as it logs the exact line that is giving the error .Also are you able to browse a simple ASP page with one line code like <%= now()%>

Comment: Eh @RaviA. the line us right there it's 24!?

Comment: Oh ya.So how about a simple ASP page. Does it works fine?

Comment: Also can you code your code that is causing issue.